# Using csv row length as variable in loop

Tags: python

I am new to python - in the script below, I am setting the variable `count` to 0 and then looping over over each row of the csv file.  When the count reaches 5, I want to script to stop, and it does.

However, in this case I know that the number of rows in the csv is 5.  What if I don't know the number of rows? I've commented out two lines that I've tried to use to give me the `row_count` and then to subsequently use the `row_count` variable **in place** of 5.  However, when I uncomment those two lines, the script just stops at `print(row_count)`.  What am I doing wrong here and how can I use the `row_count` variable further down so that `sys.exit()` happens on the last row?

```
count = 0


with open('mydata.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
     reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
     #row_count = sum(1 for row in reader)
     #print(row_count)

     for row in reader:
         count += 1
         print(count)
         if count == 5:
              sys.exit()
```

Comment: Indent your for loop to be inside your `with`. Replace `5` with `row_count`. Note you can used the `csvfile` directly instead of `reader`.

Comment: Is the data type of "reader" a list? Is "row" a dict?

Comment: I don't see why a counter is needed at all. The for loop will exit when each item has been iterated from a list. The exit command will quit the script. If the exit command is actually needed, then move it out of the for loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure to keep everything you do with the `reader` inside of the `with` block. Once the `with` block exits you can't access the reader anymore since the file is automatically closed.

```
count = 0
with open('mydata.csv', newline='') as csvfile:

    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)

    for row in reader:
        count += 1
        print(count)
```

Additionally you don't need the `sys.exit()`, your loop terminates by itself once you run out of lines. After this block of code you can use `count` wherever.